# Saída de arquivo com YAD

Tags: bash, shell-script

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou com alguns probleminhas com o uso do YAD. Tenho um shellscript super funcional e muito útil. Agora estou tentando por ele numa interface gráfica para ficar bem bonito e elegante. Problema é que o script usa saídas de diversos arquivos, coisa que não estou conseguindo fazer com o YAD :/

```
placa=$(iwconfig | cut -d" " -f 1> interface.txt)
yad --list --title="Interfaces de rede sem fio" --width=600 --heigth=800 --print-all $(cat inteface.txt | egrep -o "\w{1,}")
```

Minha real intenção seria colocar algo como:

```
placa=$(iwconfig | cut -d" " -f 1> interfaces.txt)
yad --radiolist --title="Interfaces de rede" \
--text "Escolha uma interface"\
--column "Placas"\
--width=600 --heigth=800\
false $(sed -n '1' interface.txt | egrep -o "\w{1,}")\
true $(sed -n '2' interface.txt | egrep -o "\w{1,}")
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?  Não acho nenhum material com esse tipo de conteúdo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
placa=$(iwconfig | cut -d" " -f 1> interfaces.txt)
opcao1=$(sed -n '1' interface.txt | egrep -o "\w{1,}")
opcao2=$(sed -n '2' interface.txt | egrep -o "\w{1,}")

yad --radiolist --title="Interfaces de rede" \
--text "Escolha uma interface"\
--column " " -- column "Placas"\
false "$(echo $opcao1)"  \
true "$("$(echo $opcao1)" \
--width="600" --heigth="200" )
```